# Data modeling in multiple aggregation levels

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I have a question about data modeling.

I have a table called "sales" where I store different levels of aggregation of customer sales. It has the following attributes:

```
id (integer)
period_id (integer)
customer_id (integer)
product_category_id (integer)
channel_id (integer)
value (float)
```

Depending on what "id" attributes are filled, I know the level of aggregation. For example:

If period_id, customer_id and product_category_id are filled, but channel_id is NULL, I know it's aggregated by all channels. If also product_category_id is NULL, I know it's aggregated by all channels and product categories.

Associated to each row of that sales table, I have an associate row in performance_analysis table, which store statistical analysis of those sales. This table has the following attributes:

```
sales_id (integer)
and a bunch of numerical statistical values
```

I believe that storing those different levels of aggregation in the sames (sales) table is not a good practice, and I'm planning to make some changes. My idea is to score just the most disaggregated level, and get each level of aggregation on-the-fly, using SQL to aggregate. In that scenario, all the references attributes of "sales" table will be filled, and I'll just GROUP BY and SUM according to my needs.

The problem is: by doing this, I lose the 1x1 association with the performance_analysis table. Then, I would have to move the reference attributes to the analysis table and the problem persists.

I would still have to use that NULL attributes hack to know which level of aggregation is.

It is important to notice that aggregate that analysis data is not trivial. I can't just SUM the attributes, they're specific to the analyzed values. So it's not data duplication as it is on the "sales" case. But it still have different levels of "aggregation" on the same table.

What is the best way to store that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're certainly on the right track as far as holding the sales data at its most granular. What you're describing is very much like a dimensional model's fact table, and Ralph Kimball (a key figure in dimensional modelling) would always advise that you hold your measures at the lowest grain possible. If you're not already familiar with dimensional modelling, I would suggest you do some reading into it, as you are working in a very similar way and might find some useful information, both for this particular issue and perhaps for other design decisions you need to make.

As far as your statistical values, the rules of dimensional modelling would also tell you that you simply cannot store measures which are at different grains in the same table. If you really cannot calculate them on-the-fly, then make separate tables at each aggregation level, and include the appropriate ID columns for each level.

It could be worth looking into multidimensional tools (OLAP cubes, etc.), as it's possible that rather than carrying these calculations out and then storing them in the database, you might be able to add a layer which allows those - and more - calculations to be carried out at run time. For some use cases this has obvious benefits over being restricted to only those calculations which have been defined at design time. They would certainly be an obvious fit on top of the dimensional data structure that you are creating.